# Check if array elements passed a callback in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, callback

Is there a built-in way in PHP to find if at least one element in an array pass a test or if every element passed a test?

Like in Javascript

```
myArray.some('myFunction'); //Will return true if at least one array element passed myFunction
myArray.every('myFunction'); //Will return true if every array element passed myFunction
```

I usually want to find if an element in an array is an object.
What I have done in PHP is the following:

```
//check at least one element passed a test
if(count(array_filter($array, 'is_object')) >0) {
 #code
}

//if I want to check if every element in the array is an object
if(count(array_filter($array, 'is_object')) === count($array)) {
 #code
}
```

I created my custom functions for this purpose:

```
function array_every(array $array, callable $callback) {
  return (count($array) === count(array_filter($array, $callback)));
}

function array_some(array $array, callable $callback) {
  return (count(array_filter($array, $callback)) > 0);
}
```

However, I still would like to know if there is a short, built-in way that returns true or false if at least one element passed the callback or if every element passed the callback.

Comment: Well, we will need to custom build it. I will try. We have array_map, but is far different from `some` and `every` for your use case.

Comment: suggested: move Q to Codereview SE as this code works^^

Comment: Best way for `some`/`every` is plain __loop__ with `break`. And no, there's no any built-in solution yet.

Comment: Ok, @u_mulder. Let's then wait for a new version of PHP to see what it bring to us; maybe one day it will have better functions for arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php


function array_some(callable $callback,$arr){
    foreach($arr as $ele){
        if(call_user_func($callback,$ele)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


function array_every(callable $callback,$arr){
    foreach($arr as $ele){
        if(!call_user_func($callback,$ele)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function my_callback($ele){
    return  $ele % 2 == 0;
}

var_dump(array_some('my_callback',[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]));
var_dump(array_some('my_callback',[1,3,5,7]));
var_dump(array_every('my_callback',[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]));
var_dump(array_every('my_callback',[0,2,4,6,8]));
```

As there are no built in functions, you could create your own callback function and pass it as an argument to your `array_some` and `array_every` method and return results accordingly. Following code above checks even numbers in our array. We use [call_user_func()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) to invoke a call to our callback method `my_callback` and pass the current element in foreach iteration as an argument/parameter to it and return a boolean `true` or `false` accordingly.

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/1DUDu

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! I like the fact you provided us with a Demo link. Still, I'll not mark it as the accepted answer because I'm looking for a built-in way and I hope a future version of PHP will bring it to us! By the way, sorry about the late reply.

Answer (score 2):

These functions aren't built into PHP. You might be interested in this package:

https://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php

> A set of functional primitives for PHP, heavily inspired by Scala’s traversable collection, Dojo’s array functions and Underscore.js.

It has a `some` and an `every` function.

```php
$set = ['A', 'B', 'B'];

$is_A = function($item, $collection_key, $collection) {
  return $item === 'A';
};

Functional\some($set, $is_A); // true
Functional\every($set, $is_A); // false
```